# Searching for an item in a nested list and then returning the index of an item

Tags: python, list, indexing, nested

So I was trying to write a function called find_treasure which takes a 2D list as a parameter. The purpose of the function is to search through the 2D list given and to return the index of where the 'x' is located.

```
def find_treasure(my_list):

    str1 = 'x'
    if str1 in [j for i in (my_list) for j in i]:
    index = (j for i in my_list for j in i).index(str1)
    return(index)


treasure_map = [[' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', 'x', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ']]

print(find_treasure(treasure_map))
```

However, I can't seem to get the function to return the index, I tried using the enumerate function too but either I was using it wrongly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `enumerate`

```
def find_treasure(my_list):
    str1 = 'x'
    for i,n  in enumerate(my_list):
        for j, m in enumerate(n):
            if m == str1:
                return (i, j)

treasure_map = [[' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', 'x', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ']]
print(find_treasure(treasure_map))
```

**Output:**

```
(1, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `index` function.

```
def find_treasure(my_list):
    str1 = 'x'
    for i,n  in enumerate(my_list):
        try:
          return (i, n.index(str1))
        except ValueError:
          pass

treasure_map = [[' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', 'x', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ']]
print(find_treasure(treasure_map))
```

**Output**

```
(1, 1)
```